# Convert latex mathematics equations directly to Python/Matlab Code?

Tags: matlab, python, software

I am wondering if there is any technique to convert latex mathematics equations directly to code, like Python(numpy,scipy), Matlab? Thanks!

I have this problem since I find I sometimes make mistakes in typing the equations in Python and Matlab, and it seems hard to find the bug sometimes.I also find vectorization is a problem that sometimes I forget to transpose or flatten the vectors in Python, and it is ruined.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Theano is the answer!

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Can-sympy-library-be-used-in-machine-learning

Comment: Could @Glen_b re-open this problem? I think I get the answer. Thanks!